# Samsung Galaxy S Advance Continuous Focus in Video Recording

Tags: video-recording, samsung-galaxy-s-advance

I am interested in Samsung Galaxy S Advance. But I noticed that this phone does not have Continuous Focus function in the Video Recording. How can I have Continuous Focus function in Video Recording? Is there any apps that can solve this?